# NVDA not announcing the expand status

Tags: typescript, accessibility, angular8, mozilla, nvda

I am facing an issue with aria-expanded. Copying the code below.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of details; let i = index;">
            <tr>
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button 
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        attr.data-target="#{{getId(i)}}" 
                        attr.aria-controls="{{getId(i)}}"
                        (click)="addExpandClass()">
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr attr.id="{{getId(i)}}" role="presentation">
                <td colspan="2">data</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`addExpandClass()` => add or remove the 'expand' css class.

Issue: NVDA reader is not announcing 'expanded' status for the first time. And everything is working fine from second time. Can someone help me on this please.

Note:  **If I remove the logic to add OR remove the css class, then everything is working as expected.**

Thanks for the help

Comment: @Beta there is nothing wrong with the code as you posted and it announces correctly for me. Is this static HTML or is this rendered from a JavaScript template as it could be an issue with when the accessibility tree is constructed and when the `aria-expanded` is applied. Also note you do need the `aria-controls` attribute as @Josh said to link the two sections together otherwise telling people that something is expanded is pointless.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thanks for the response. I have updated the code with full context. it's a static html. If remove the logic to add OR remove the css class, then everything is working as expected

Comment: my angular knowledge is limited so bear with me. Where is `aria-expanded` set in the first place? I don't see it on your `attr` so is this being set by you dynamically / by Angular? Additionally you have the `addExpandClass` function, does that purely add a class or does that also update the `aria-expanded` attribute (or yet again is that functionality baked into Angular?) As an aside:- i would question the `role="presentation"` on an item that is being controlled, that effectively removes all semantic meaning & doesn't seem correct from the example given, hard to judge out of context though.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie sorry, missed to add the aria-expanded in the sample code. Updated the code with same. addExpandClass is only to add the css class to the table row to highlight the same.

Comment: To cover the point you made about the spec, yes you can add `aria-expanded` to any element if it has the correct `role` assigned to it. The relationship is always `aria-expanded` on the parent / controlling item as this lets a screen reader know that the section it controls is opened. If it was on the section that was collapsed the screen reader might never access it (as the collapsed section could be hidden). The easiest way to remember which way around they go, "controlling button is always visible so that is where the information should be", or at least that is how I remember it.

Comment: @beta everything looks fine in your example now, do you happen to be able to put a fiddle together that shows this issue as from what you have shown it should work. Just FYI applying a CSS class only will not update the expanded state, you need to change the `aria-expanded="true"` at the same time. Put a fiddle together and I will show you how it should work and put comments in to explain each of the steps. As for it not working first time this is nearly always down to a race condition / load order issue where the item is added to the accessibility tree before the attribute is set.